# Apply XOR operation to an array of bytes?

Tags: powershell

I have an array of bytes :

```
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($myFile)
```

I would like to perform a XOR operation on each byte inside this array, like this (in python)

```
bytes[i] ^= 0x6A  // python-style
```

I tried

```
for($i=0; $i -lt $bytes.count ; $i++)
{
    $bytes[$i] = $bytes[$i] -xor 0x6A
}
```

But does not work : $bytes[$i] value is 0x00.

How can this be done in powershell ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`-xor` is a logical operator returning True or False.  Perhaps you want to use bitwise exclusive OR'ing via `-bxor`?

```
for($i=0; $i -lt $bytes.count ; $i++)
{
    $bytes[$i] = $bytes[$i] -bxor 0x6A
}
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks. Didn't see that operator -_-